# Modelling the Implied volatility of an asset

Tags: options, black-scholes, european-options

I want to estimate the implied volatility of an asset which has not historical implied volatility data. I do have the historical realized volatility ( I have the historical prices). What would be some of the basic ways to estimate the IV and hence price an option using black scholes?

Comment: You should not rely on HV. See for example, [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76367/54838) for an explanation. You could use a comparable underlying as a proxy and potentially do some adjustments. There are quite a few similar questions here though: [1](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/55727/54838), [2](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/55335/54838); [3](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/31121/54838)...